# In Foc, when Including a sub form programmatically does not save its content with parent form

Tags: java, vaadin

I am using [focframework](https://github.com/FOC-framework/framework)

I have included programmatically a form, but when I click **Apply** on the Parent form to trigger a save to DB, the child changes are not saved, only parent changes are saved.

This is how I added the form programmatically, I did put the line `setParentLayout()`:

```
//Get the vertical layout where we want to add the new sub form
FVVerticalLayout verticalLayout = getComponentByName("_VERTICAL_LAYOUT");

//Create the view Key
XMLViewKey key = new XMLViewKey(MyEntityDesc.getInstance().getStorageName(), XMLViewKey.TYPE_FORM);

//Using the Key build my Form and send my user data myFocObject
FocXMLLayout myForm = XMLViewDictionary.getInstance().newCentralPanel(getMainWindow(), key, myFocObject);

//Add my Form to the verticalLayout
verticalLayout.addComponent(myForm);

//Tell the form that the "this" form class is the parent layout
myForm.setParentLayout(this);
```

Answer (score 0):

To make the "save" applied to a parent layout propagate to the child layout and save it, you need to specify that by setting the flag commitWithParent:

```
myForm.setCommitWithParent();
```

If the include is done using the XML tag you can set that flag using the related attribute as follows:

```
<HorizontalLayout captionMargin="0" spacing="true" margin="true" visibleWhen="Anonymous=false">
    <IncludeXML dataPath="Empl" storage="Employee" type="Form" commitWithParent="true" />
</HorizontalLayout>
```

NB: When the include is done using the XML tag the default flag value is "true". While when adding the layout using the code the default value is false.